# SQL Server 2012 FileTables to store images for hosting in IIS8 virtual directory

Tags: web-applications, sql-server-2012, virtual-directory, iis-8, filetable

I'm having a pretty specific problem regarding hosting images (for display on a web page) in an IIS8 virtual directory mapped to a SQL Server 2012 FileStream share. When I attempt to browse to the URL corresponding to the virtual directory the images don't always load.

I have confirmed the permissions are set correctly in IIS to browse the network share mapped to the virtual directory, but for some reason I get a 500.19 (sc-win32-status: 50) error on certain images.

I can't figure out why some images work and others don't when all have the same permission levels.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If I'm not supposed to map directly to this share for serving files, how can I map to it in IIS?

Here's an error entry in IIS8 for this problem:

> *2013-02-24 20:06:52 192.168.0.50 GET /thumbImages/thumbs_02967_theoldfishinghut_1920x1080.jpg - 80 - 98.155.90.44 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.17+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/24.0.1312.57+Safari/537.17 - 500 19 50 2*

The strange thing is the images will sometimes load if I reload the web page they are on enough times. I have also observed the larger images never load but smaller images will load on occasion (and once they are cached the web page will load them without issue).

Thanks!

Comment: details about 500 errors should be in the server's error log.

Comment: The error posted above is the only error I could find from the IIS8 error logs for the problem. I didn't see anything in the event viewer on the server.

Comment: that's not an error log entry. that a normal access log (e.g. every hit goes there).

Comment: Gotcha, sorry about the confusion. That said the access log seems to be all I have to work with, unless there's something beyond the event logs available.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems like this problem is too obscure or perhaps I didn't present it in the best way.

In any event the only solution I could think of that still utilizes the FileStream share is a terrible one - just mirror the share onto a different folder and serve the files from the mirrored folder. Hopefully a better solution comes along later.